# Codeblock does not run c++ program

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Codeblock runs perfectly for any c program.but does not run any c++ program. even the hello world. it shows this error:

"fatal error iostream: No such file or directory"

I tried this simple codes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Update: This question was posted by my wife using my account. She studied accounting. Now I can't delete this question.

Comment: You need to use g++ for C++ program. It looks like it is using gcc for C program.

Comment: What is the name of your C++ source file? More specifically, what is the extension?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem is that CodeBlocks is compiling your C++ as a C program.

Please do the following:

1) Make sure you've installed a compatible C++ compiler:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler

2) Make sure you've saved the file in your project as a ".cpp" (C++ source file)

3) You can also search your filesteam for "iostream".  For example, MSVC puts it here on my Windows hard drive:

D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include

4) It sounds like you're following these instructions:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project

If you're still having problems, please specify what platform you're on (Windows?  Linux?) and what compiler you're using (g++?  MSVC?)